# Debugging .NET memory leaks - how to know what is holding a reference to what?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am working on a .NET application where there appears to be a memory leak. I know the text-book answers, that events should be unsubscribed, disposable objects should be disposed etc...

I have a test harness that can reproduce the error. In the finalizer of a certain class I write to console

```
public class Foo
{
   // Ctor
   public Foo()
   {
   }

   ~public Foo()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Foo Finalized");
   }
}
```

In the test harness, I am creating a single instance of Foo (which in turn creates and interacts with hundreds of other types) then removing it and invoking the Garbage collector.

I am finding the Foo Finalizer is never called. I have a similar class with this setup which is finalized as a control test.

So my question is this:

> How can I determine using commercial or open source tools exactly what
>   is holding a reference to Foo?

I have a professional license to dotTrace Memory profiler but can't figure out from the help files how to use it.

**Update:** I am now using [dotMemory 4.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), which is the successor to the (good, but unusable) dotTrace Memory 3.5.

Comment: if you already have a profiler learn to use it - I did not work with dotTrace very much but I the other two are similar in there use-patterns and need some "getting into" too

Comment: @CarstenKönig +1 to this, I'm digging around in dotTrace now. Figured out I can find a list uncollected objects by namespace (so found my offending Foo) and what holds a reference to them, again filtered by namespace (hundreds of), now going through a list of suspicious event handlers etc...

Comment: @CarstenKönig In fact, found it using dotTrace! It does have the feature to drill down into the graph from gcroot -> Foo, just a little difficult to find. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finalizer isn't deterministically called, so beware of using it to track things in a reliable way. If you remove the finalizer and instead use a `WeakReference<Foo>` you should be able to determine whether the object was collected.

All memory profilers should be able to find an issue such as this, but with varying degree of difficulty. I have personally used ANTS which is very easy yo use, but not free. It will help you show a reference diagram to the Foo instance, all the way from a GC root object. Seeing this diagram it is usually easy to spot who is holding the reference.

Comment: I have tired 3 different profilers and cant see if what I'm seeing is a leak and or where its coming from. I am aware of all the normal got ya traps, just need someone who can be a rubber duck who has a fairly gd understanding of memory allocation and retention  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575338/memory-leak-cant-find-where-the-allocations-originate-from-or-why-they-being-hel i believe what im seeing is a bug in .net core code rather than my own, but hard to tell, as there are like 0 clues. So could be chasing a dead end.

Answer (score 7):

Have a [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) at the [SOS debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764(v=vs.110).aspx) extension (It's free, an can be used within Visual Studio).

You may find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx) and [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/investigating-.net-memory-management-and-garbage-collection/) helpful to get startet.

If you have succefully set up SOS (this can be tricky sometimes), knowing what holds a reference to what is as easy as

```
// load sos
.load sos
// list of all instances of YourTypeName in memory with their method tables
!DumpHeap -type YourTypeName  
// put here the method table displayed by the previous command
// it will show you the memory address of the object
!DumpHeap -mt 07f66b44              
// displays information about references the object at the specified address
!GCRoot 02d6ec94
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll definitely give it a try. Would be nice if there was a good tutorial on dotTrace but sadly no!

Answer (score 6):

Debugging memory leaks can be quite involved process and requires thorough understanding of your program logic and at least some .Net internals (especially garbage collector behaviour).

For more information see the following links:

**Good introduction**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658248.aspx

**Hands-on course:**

- http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article508.aspx
- http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article524.aspx

**GC and .Net internals**

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx

**WinDbg with SOS extension**

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19490/Memory-Leak-Detection-in-NET
- http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/investigating-.net-memory-management-and-garbage-collection/

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use memory profilers to identify the memory leaks. Here are some,

[MemProfiler](http://memprofiler.com/)

[ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Comment: Voted up for ANTS Profiler. In a reasonably large enterprise application, managed to find a huge resource leak that had escaped detection for 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you shouldn't use a finalizer, because:

> Finalize operations have the following limitations:
>
> - The exact time when the finalizer executes during garbage collection
>     is undefined. Resources are not guaranteed to be released at any
>     specific time, unless calling a Close method or a Dispose method.
> - The finalizers of two objects are not guaranteed to run in any
>     specific order, even if one object refers to the other. That is, if
>     Object A has a reference to Object B and both have finalizers, Object
>     B might have already finalized when the finalizer of Object A starts.
> - The thread on which the finalizer is run is unspecified.

Quote from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx
I would suggest using Dispose method instead.

Secondly, any memory profiler should be able to find what holds those references. Personally I was using ANTS Profiler, it's a very nice tool and has quite rich documentation. You can try reading this doc: http://downloads.red-gate.com/HelpPDF/ANTS_Memory_Profiler/InstanceCategorizer.pdf
Instance categorizer displays chains of references from sets of objects to GC root.

Comment: While you're totally right, in some cases its really necessary to use Finalizer. Consider you created a custom control to render 3D surfaces which you redistribute to end-users. End users are very unlikely to call .Dispose() on your control once it is no longer in use. They expect it to 'just work'. Also WPF garbage collects views sometimes when they are templated and in a tab-control and tabbed out and in. In these cases its impossible to call .Dispose and the Finalizer is the best option to release unmanaged resources by directly calling Dispose for you, if not already