# Finding memory leaks in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, memory-footprint

I have an application in C#, Framework 4. Very basically, this application mainly react to events and creates objects, release them, create database connection and close them.

Now, we've been seeing that the application's process grows sometimes in very strange ways. We've got two different behaviors :

1. The application grows until reaching up to 4 GB in RAM when usually it "should" stay at around 500 MB. Consequence -> it crashes!
2. The application grows slowly up to 1200 MB (30 minutes) and then abruptly shrinks to 500 MB (in one second)... and this process repeats itself every now and then. Can this be Garbage Collector in action ?

Now, in order to provide us with more informations about the application, I would like to add in our log files the size of the application's process. Is it possible through the native framework ? Is it possible to know an object' size in C# ?

I've also found the application NetMemoryProfiler4 but I would prefer to use embedded logging if it's possible !

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is a `Mo`?

Comment: Using a memory profiler will give you more information and let you target leaks much more effectively than logging.

Comment: You've never heard of a MegaOyte?

Comment: @codesparkle maybe he's french and it's Mo == Mega Octet == Mega Byte

Comment: @codesparkle: it's french for MB (Méga-octet)

Comment: @codesparkle: Mo -> MegaOctet; Go -> GigaOctet or something like that in french...

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. I edited, changing it to the more common (English) form.

Comment: my bad :) I do speak french and forgot to change it to Gb and Mb !

Comment: @Oded I know but our application are very client oriented and we cannot spend time using a profiler at each of our customer. It would be more convenient to consult our log files and get the process' size within those log files.

Comment: Process size will tell you nothing about what causes the leak.

Comment: No but having a process unnecessary high after some calls will maybe guide us! And furthermore, profiling is not always posible for us because we dont have access to the application...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need memory profiler to debug such problems. For example:

- [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273)
- [.Net Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/dotnet-memory.php)
- [GlowCode](http://www.glowcode.com/)
- [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Also see suggestions from [the other question about memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133722/debugging-net-memory-leaks-how-to-know-what-is-holding-a-reference-to-what).

Basically, this boils down to finding the objects in memory that stay here while they shouldn't. It can be event handler holding reference to its class or some collection of objects holding references to their parents, and so on. After finding the root cause you may need to restructure your application to get rid of the unnecessary references. This can be as simple as adding forgotten event unsubscription but in non trivial cases might require applying some structural design patterns. This part is very application specific.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Process` class is the right thing you are searching.
Use `Process myProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess()` to get current process.
Then you can use `myProcess`´s [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like `WorkingSet64`, `PrivateMemorySize64` and so on.