# WebBrowser / Explorer crashes and stays crashed until application restart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

In my application (WinForms) I use WebBrowser to display reports. The WebBrowser is a part of a from and is **disposed** every time user closes the report form.

Randomly, but regularly something crashes. When it crashes it stays crashed until I restart the application. **After application restart everything is back to normal**. It happens on Windows 10.

Symptoms:

1) Images (loaded from **local file system**) do not display. Sometimes they do not show up at all, sometimes a small "X" symbol show up instead of image:
[image]. Images are not very large (0.5 MB max). HTML is fine (opened manually in a browser looks fine).

2) Crashed explorer in save file dialog

- missing navigation tree on the left
- black squares instead of some icons
- some icons change (see the Computer icon)

[image]

After application restart it looks ok:

[image]

What could be the reason for the crash? How to prevent it?

Comment: [Memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5020814/1997232). [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12474321/1997232) for them (I recommend dotMemory).

Comment: Could you show some sample code?  Is WebBrowser a COM object?  COM objects need to be handled with great care, and if not, often result in bizarre crashes like you are experiencing.

Comment: @RikRak Unfortunately I connot extract a code sample. However It's a simple form with standard System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control.

Comment: @gisek it's going to be difficult for anyone to help you without a code sample I think :-(