# windows service + nhibernate - sharp architecture - memory leakage?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, windows-services, s#arp-architecture

I have a windows service that performs bulk inserts triggered by a time. I am using sharp (contrib) architecture and NHibernate. The service's memory consumption seems to go up slowly/linearly over time. I would like to investigate what causes this. Could anyone please be so kind and recommend a tool? Thanks.

Comment: Are you clearing the session between each trigger?

Comment: Yes: NHibernateSession.Current.Clear();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are commercial profilers ([ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/), [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), etc) but also the excellent [SOS debugger extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx), which you can use from Visual Studio or WinDbg. There are [many](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paullou/archive/2011/06/28/debugging-managed-code-memory-leak-with-memory-dump-using-windbg.aspx) [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2007/10/19/net-finalizer-memory-leak-debugging-with-sos-dll-in-visual-studio.aspx) [about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133722/debugging-net-memory-leaks-how-to-know-what-is-holding-a-reference-to-what) to use SOS. [Tess Ferrandez' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) is an excellent resource on debugging.

Typically, you will use SOS similar to this. First run:

```
!EEHeap
```

to check the status of the heap, followed by

```
!dumpheap -stat
```

to see what is the type of the leaked objects. From there, you can use

```
!dumpheap -type <object type>
```

to list the objects and then

```
!gcroot <object address>
```

for a specific object, to see which roots are keeping the object alive.

However, I always start with checking the GC performance counters in such cases, to understand the leak pattern, see which heap is growing etc.